# does anyone use OSX Xboard app in Mavericks?

Tags: software

There's been talk about this app's release but I don't seem to be able to track it down and download it.  I'd love to have Xboard native app for my Mac.  Can anyone help?  Any help appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Winboard is what can run in wine. Though macwine is limited to 32bit executables.   Xboard on the other hand always could be compiled in OSX just fine!  I created an .app package ready for use and I'm told works fine in 10.10-10.6

It is a GTK2 app running through Quartz, so no X11 server app is needed.

http://www.open-aurec.com:8080/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=53274&p=200662#p200662

Comment: Maybe you should point out that you're the author for the package.

Comment: Fair point,  Perhaps I assumed too much of the statement "I have an .app package ready for use..."

Answer (score 0):

Ummm. https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/whats_new/4.8.0/index.html

> With XBoard 4.8.0 the GTK build can be considered as stable as the Xaw build. In some areas it might not be perfect yet in all areas, but in other areas, such as the ICS Interaction window, it is already developed beyond the Xaw version, and the GTK build is in general superior to the obsolete Xaw interface.
>
> The GTK build can also be interfaced with OS X through the GtkOsx library. So OS X is now amongst the officially supported platforms, and a special configure option is available to build XBoard as OS X App.

That having been said, I haven't used it. It would appear from the notes that's not only able to be built as an OS X app, but an app bundle can be found here: http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=53274

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I know the OP said "native" but I suspect I and @grgarside have different definitions of the word "native". To me "native" means "not in an emulator or other virtual machine." And XBoard meets that definition, because X11 apps run right alongside other OS X apps in the same machine, without either virtualization or emulation.

Comment: Your answer is kind of duplicate to Joshua Pettus's answer. Joshua is the author of the bundle.